# Parallel arrays for finding the highest element

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I want to find the highest element in the "prices" array then print the corresponding element in the "letters" array

I need some suggestions about what I can do. I have tried outputting letters[index] but I get an error because of the scope I think. I'm very new to coding so this is really stumping me right now.

```
  String[] letters = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
  double[] prices = {1.00, 2.00, 50.00, 4.00, 5.00, 6.00, 7.00};
  double big = prices[0];      
  //for loop to find the highest value in the array
   for(int index = 0; index < prices.length; index++)  
   { 
    if(prices[index] > big)
     {
        big = prices[index];     
     }             
   }       
 System.out.println("The letter with the highest value is " + big);
```

Comment: Don't use parallel arrays, create objects that combine those two values, then find the object with the highest price.

Answer (score 1):

You need two variables: one to keep track of the current "highest values" and one to keep track of the index of this value.

```java
double big = prices[0];
int bigIndex = 0;
```

then

```java
if (prices[index] > big) {
    big = prices[index];
    bigIndex = index;
}
```

and finally:

```java
System.out.println("The letter with the highest value is " + letters[bigIndex]);
```